# Problems with the return option

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, escaping

I am working on a simple program in Python, when a big doubt came to me.

I know that, to create a new line in Python it is sufficient to print the escape charatcter '\n'

However, this does not work when I am working on a function. I'll make a simple example:

```
def exponential(n):
      return n**2, n**3, n**4
```

If i want to see these three result on three different lines, what can I do?

I've tried with the escape character '\n', but using return, I see '\n' in the output

Comment: `print("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(exponential(5)))` should do the job.

Comment: Chester - why not add this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Do that when you're printing the results

```
n2, n3, n4 = exponential(5)
print(n2, n3, n4, sep="\n")
```